# DmfEntityProxy not found in AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Openning *DMFParameters* form shows next error:

- Error Assembly containing type `Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Tools.DMF.ServiceProxy.DmfEntityProxy` is not referenced.
- Error Object 'CLRObject' could not be created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is at `\Data Dictionary\Tables\DMFParameters\Methods\getServiceConnectionUrl` (Line: 19):

> ```cs
> dmfEntityProxy = new CLRObject('Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Framework.Tools.DMF.ServiceProxy.DmfEntityProxy');
> ```

Install Client (on the client) and Server (on the server) DMF components **and** **restart AOS**.
[image: AX 2012 Setup - DIXF Components]

More: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn720760.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed AX Data migration components correctly.